# Jmeter How to use different user variables for each thread (each thread. not thread group)

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, threadgroup

I want to use 100 concurrent users in one thread group in Jmeter. but I want to each thread to use different user login password. how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

full credit to Apache *Jmeter* documentation:

Some test plans need to use different values for different users/threads. For example, you might want to test a sequence that requires a unique login for each user. This is easy to achieve with the facilities provided by JMeter.

For example:

Create a text file containing the user names and passwords, separated by commas. Put this in the same directory as your test plan.
Add a CSV *DataSet* configuration element to the test plan. Name the variables USER and PASS.
Replace the login name with ${USER} and the password with ${PASS} on the appropriate samplers
The CSV Data Set element will read a new line for each thread.

UPDATE documentation link

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options depending on where do you want to keep the credentials.

- The most commonly used approach is storing login/password combinations in the CSV file and using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for reading them. By default each JMeter thread will read the next line from the file on each iteration
- If your credentials are in the database you can use [JDBC PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PreProcessor)
- If you plan to run your test in Distributed Mode and don't want to worry about copying test data to all slave machines - there are [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) and [Redis Data Set Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/)

More information: [JMeter Parameterization - The Complete Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide)